# How to Convert multiple rows into one with comma as separator - Oracle db

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle table which has id and order_id columns. Table have same order_id with different id's.

How can I write a select for group same order_ids, and show in one line which seperated with comma;

```
Example;

      ORDER_ID                ID
623cdc7ff2f3603b06a283ff    8112686  
623cdc7ff2f3603b06a283ff    8116869
623cdc7ff2f3603b06a28400    8117671
623ce4068c47be1532c4c53c    8118392
```

Select result should be like that;

```
ORDER_ID                    ID
623cdc7ff2f3603b06a283ff    8112686 , 8116869
623cdc7ff2f3603b06a28400    8117671
623ce4068c47be1532c4c53c    8118392
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LISTAGG

```
Select ORDER_ID, LISTAGG(ID, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID)
From tbl
Group By ORDER_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

listagg function to the rescue:

```
select order_id, listagg(id,', ')
from test
group by order_id
```

Comment: Missing the mandatory `within group (order by ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Or, for older versions of Oracle you can use WM_CONCAT function. LISTAGG appeared at Oracle 11g Release 2.

```
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            SELECT '623cdc7ff2f3603b06a283ff' "ORDER_ID", '8112686' "ID" FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
            SELECT '623cdc7ff2f3603b06a283ff' "ORDER_ID", '8116869' "ID" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT '623cdc7ff2f3603b06a28400' "ORDER_ID", '8117671' "ID" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT '623ce4068c47be1532c4c53c' "ORDER_ID", '8118392' "ID" FROM DUAL 
        )
--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Select ORDER_ID, WMSYS.WM_CONCAT(ID)
From tbl
Group By ORDER_ID
```

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't recommend anyone to use undocumented & unsupported features (such as WM_CONCAT)

Comment: Thanks Littlefoot - here is a disclaimer, though the function works ok for me with older versions of Oracle. WM_CONCAT is an undocumented function and as such is not supported by Oracle for user applications (MOS Note ID 1336219.1). If this concerns you, make a User-Defined Aggregate Function.